# LDAP changing password for wrong user?

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, openldap, pam

I have an OpenLDAP server setup. I currently have two users added to my server. As far as my testing goes, a single user instance work just perfectly. My first issue arise when i have two users on the LDAP repository.

Directly after adding my 2nd user, i have attempted to login to my linux machine, and it's always asking me to change password when it's the first login (which is perfect).

Although, when i log-in with my first temporary password, you can see in the output below that **User2 is attempting to log in**, but then when it's asking to change the password, **it's attempting to change it for User1**.

```
login as: user2
Authenticating with public key "user2-rsa-key"
Further authentication required
user1@x.x.x.x's password:
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
You are required to change your LDAP password immediately.
Last login: 'Date' From 'Hostname'
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user user1.    <----- This is where it messes up !
Enter login(LDAP) password:
```

I beleive this is an issue with my ACL, so i will let you guys see what my current acls are on the olcDatabase={2}bdb.ldif

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to * by dn.base="cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com" write by self write by * read
```

Now assuming it's not an issue with my ACL's, I am wondering if it's simply how I add users to my LDAP server.
I normally add users using this command :

```
ldapadd -x -W -D "cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com" -f user.ldif
```

Finally, here is the output on what there currently is on my server

```
[root@localhost ~]# ldapsearch -x -W -D "cn=admin,dc=domain,dc=com" -b "dc=domain,dc=com" "(objectclass=*)"
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=domain,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#
# domain.com
dn: dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: domain.com
dc: domain
# users, domain.com
dn: ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: users
# groups, domain.com
dn: ou=groups,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: groups
# user1, users, domain.com
dn: uid=user1,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: ldapPublicKey
cn: user1
uid: user1
uidNumber: 16859
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/user1
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: user1
shadowMax: 0
shadowWarning: 0
sshPublicKey: some rsa keys
userPassword:: crypted password
shadowLastChange: 16991

# user2, users, domain.com
dn: uid=user2,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: ldapPublicKey
cn: user2
uid: user2
uidNumber: 16859
gidNumber: 100
homeDirectory: /home/user2
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: user2
shadowLastChange: 0
shadowMax: 0
shadowWarning: 0
sshPublicKey: some rsa keys
userPassword:: crypted password
# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success
# numResponses: 6
# numEntries: 5
```

Comment: This line doesnt seem right at all,   
uidNumber: 16859  
, same uid number for both users, seems to me that is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your user definitions include `uidNumber: 16859`. The scenario you describe where *user2*'s password change actually updates the password for *user1* is likely due to LDAP locating the user account for which to change the password by searching the `uid`, locating it in the *user1* entry, and applying the new password. I'm not an expert with LDAP but it seems logical a `uidNumber` collision in LDAP would produce this result, though it seems odd for openLDAP to even allow two entries to have the same value for such a critical property.

Thank you for providing details on your overall setup so a second set of eyes on the issue could spot the potential culprit.